# HornetQ: Divert + Transformer class usage

Tags: hornetq, transformer-model

I was looking forward to using a divert on HornetQ to divert messages on a given address to many other addresses. What I would like to do is add some additional properties on the message ONCE it gets diverted. It seems like I can use a transformer class to do just that. My only question is that I would like to add custom properties based on the divert that the message came on. I am not sure how to get that info.

Example: 
address.order -> divert it to address.electronicorder, address.bookorder, address.clothorder.

Now once it gets diverted; I would like to add a property (like "ORDER TYPE") on the message in the transformer.. but I am not sure how I can get the divert that the message came on..

Any tips?